# Computing the expected quadratic variation of a Brownian bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation, brownian-bridge

Consider the Brownian bridge process $$B_t = W_t - tW_1,$$ where $W_t$ be a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$. What is the expected quadratic variation of $B_t$?

**Definition:** The co-variation of two stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ is defined by $$[X,Y]_t := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})(Y_{t_i} - Y_{t_{i-1}}),$$ where $[t_i,t_{i-1}]\in \Pi_n$ for $i=1,2,..n$  and $(\Pi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$ with mesh converging to zero. The quadratic variation of a stochastic process $Z_t$ is then $[Z,Z]_t$.

**My approach:** For stochastic processes $X_t,Y_t,Z_t,C_t$, where $C_t = c$ for all $t$, it holds that

1. $[X + C, Y]_t = [X,Y]_t$,
2. $[CX, Y]_t = C[X,Y]$,
3. $[X,Y] = [Y,X]$,
4. $[X+Y,Z]_t = [X,Z]_t + [Y,Z]_t$.

Let $I_t = t$. Then \begin{align*} [B,B]_t &= [W - IW_1,W - IW_1]_t \\ &= [W,W]_t - [W, IW_1]_t - [IW_1,W]_t + [IW_1,IW_1]_t \\ &= [W,W]_t - 2[W,IW_1]_t + [IW_1,IW_1]_t \\ &= [W,W]_t - 2W_1[W,I]_t + W_1^2[I,I]_t.\end{align*} Since $[W,W]_t = t$ and $\mathbb E[W_1] = 0$ and $\mathbb E[W_1^2] = 1$, taking expectations yields $$\mathbb E[B,B]_t = t - [I,I]_t.$$

Is this correct?

*Edit:* Apparently my calculations were not correct. I used that $\mathbb E[W_1[W,I]_t] = \mathbb E[W_1]\mathbb E[[W,I]_t]$. But this relation may not hold. For example, in the case $t=1$. In that case, the term $W_1$ also appears in $[W,I]_1$, and it's a trivial result that a constant random variable is uncorrelated with itself.

The correct approach would be to use the fact that $I$ is continuous with bounded variation, as explained in the comments.

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})({t_i} - {t_{i-1}}) \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n({t_i} - {t_{i-1}})^2}$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Since the mesh $\sup_{i=1}^n\vert t_i - t_{i-1}\vert$ converges to zero by assumption it follows that the second factor converges to zero as \begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^n({t_i} - {t_{i-1}})^2 &\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\vert{t_i} - {t_{i-1}}\vert\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\vert{t_i} - {t_{i-1}}\vert\right) \\ &\leq \sup_{i=1}^n\vert t_i - t_{i-1}\vert \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\vert{t_i} - {t_{i-1}}\vert\right) \\ &=\sup_{i=1}^n\vert t_i - t_{i-1}\vert t_n \\ & \leq \sup_{i=1}^n\vert t_i - t_{i-1}\vert t.\end{align*} Hence the terms $[W,I]_t$ and $[I,I]_t$ vanish. The quadratic variation of a Brownian bridge is therefore $$[B]_t = t.$$ In fact, the quadratic variation of a Brownian bridge is deterministic.

Comment: Correct . If you use the fact that $[I,I]_t$ vanishes you find that $B$ and $W$ have the same quadratic variation. See also this blog by [George Lowther](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/03/29/brownian-bridges/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It reassures me that you confirm my result. However, I don't see why $[I,I]_t$ vanishes? Furthermore, the blog post states that the quadratic variation of a BM is the same as those of a BB. In my above steps I used that $W_1$ and $W_t$ are independent for $t\neq 1$. So this is apparently not necessary/not correct. It would be nice if you could add some more details; what is the correct argument to show that the middle term vanishes and what is the correct argument to show that the last term vanishes?

Comment: 1. $I_t=t$ has finite variation and therefore zero quadratic variation. 2. In your steps you only need that $W_1$ does not depend on $t$. You can use the **Definition** that you have given to see that $W_1$ can be pulled out. 3. Lastly $[B,B]_t=t$ ( you do not even need the $\mathbb E$ there).

Comment: ahhh, thank you. Of course, I have seen the result before but did not think about using it for 1.). For 2.): I see that $[W,IW_1]_t = W_1[W,I]_t$. The blog post suggests that this term vanishes without using the expected value. I don't see how though

Comment: $[W,I]_t$ vanishes again because $I$ has finite variation. [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/314805/304394) is a proof.